# Android Management API Installation Policies

Tags: android, google-api, android-management-api, device-policy-manager, emm

I enrolled work profiles on 2 android tablets and apply them

```
import json

policy_name = enterprise_name + '/policies/policy1'

policy_json = '''
{
"passwordRequirements": {
  "passwordMinimumLength": 6,
  "passwordQuality": "ALPHABETIC"
},
"applications": [{
  "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT",
  "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
  "packageName": "com.google.android.gm"
   },
  {
  "installType": "AVAILABLE",
  "packageName": "com.google.android.apps.docs"
},
 {
      "packageName": "com.google.samples.apps.iosched",
      "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED"
    },
{
      "packageName": "com.google.android.apps.androidify",
      "installType": "AVAILABLE"
    },
    {
      "packageName": "com.google.android.apps.youtube",
      "installType": "AVAILABLE"
    }
],

"parentProfilePasswordRequirements": {
  "passwordMinimumLength": 4,
  "passwordQuality": "NUMERIC_COMPLEX"
}
}
'''

androidmanagement.enterprises().policies().patch(
    name=policy_name,
    body=json.loads(policy_json)
).execute()
```

after waiting a while I found that only the Gmail and Google I/O Apps are downloaded and only google drive is available in google play! all the others are not available . why is it that only google apps can be downloaded.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuHHv.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpPTe.jpg)

it seemed like it only working for google apps.
can anyone help me get through it. I need to be able to force install any package I want.

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking, you’re using an incorrect package name. Kindly change the package name for youtube and androidify:

Youtube: com.google.android.youtube
Androidify: com.valleydevfest.androidify

You can determine the package name for an application using the id parameter from the Play Store’s URL for the application.

For example, the Play Store link for YouTube is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube

In addition, If you want to install all the apps automatically, kindly change the [installType](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#installtype) to “FORCE_INSTALLED”.